# Dynamically (in runtime) change properties of standard spring integration end-points

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, integration

I want to dynamically (in runtime) change properties of standard spring integration end-points (eg jms:message-driven-channel-adapter etc.) by getting property values from the application user interface.
In this case, the spring-integration configuration is defined in xml. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Spring cloud provides [@RefreshScope](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Greenwich.SR2/multi/multi__spring_cloud_context_application_context_services.html#refresh-scope) beans which are refreshed when a property is changed. You can use this type of bean can be reinitialized after for example,  application properties are changed.

Take a look at [spring-reloading-properties](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-reloading-properties) for more details.